# RxJava Delay the response conditionally

Tags: rx-java2, rx-android

I would like to delay the response at maximum for 500milliseconds.
If updateData has taken say 400 milliseconds then I would like to delay for 100 milliseconds.

With below code always I am delaying 500milliseconds.
At the moment If backend taking 600 milliseconds then the total delay is 1100 milliseconds but I would like not to delay if it's over 500 milliseconds.

```
compositeDisposable.add(someRepo.updateData(dataRequest)
.observeOn(schedulerProvider.mainThread())
.delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.subscribeWith(dataUpdateObserver())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. Start a timer parellally when you start `someRepo.updateData(dataRequest)`. Then on complete of `someRepo.updateData(dataRequest)` get the timer count and find the required delay.

If it has alreay exceeded 500milliseconds, no further delay is required. else find the required delay  (500 - elapsedTime).  Following code does the same. Here `someRepo.updateData(dataRequest)` returns `Single<DataResponse>`

```
   Subject<Boolean> timerStopper = PublishSubject.create(); // To terminate the timer
   Observable<Long> timer = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .takeUntil(timerStopper).publish().refCount();


   someRepo.updateData(dataRequest).doOnSubscribe(__ -> timer.subscribe())
  .flatMap(dataResponse -> timer.flatMapSingle(elapsed -> {
         timerStopper.onNext(true); // take the elapsed time and terminate the timer
         long requiredDelay = elapsed > MAX_DELAY ? 0 : MAX_DELAY - elapsed; // find the required delay from elapsed. If its already exceeded Maximum delay, no delay is required
         Log.d(TAG, "requiredDelay: " + requiredDelay);
         return Single.fromCallable(() -> dataResponse).delay(requiredDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);})
        .map(data -> data).firstOrError())
   .subscribeWith(dataUpdateObserver());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define a global variable to get the total time of your updateData operation and depending how much time it took, you use a delay value

```
long total = 0;

@Test
public void customDelay() {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Subscription subscription = Observable.just("hello reactive world with custom delay")
            .map(value -> {
                //updateData logic
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(600));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                total = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
                if (total > 500) total = 0;
                return value;
            })
            .delay(total, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe(n -> System.out.println("time:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)));
    new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription).awaitTerminalEvent(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

You can see the example running here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/utils/ObservableDelay.java

Comment: Hi @paul Thanks for your help. But in my case Single<DataResponse> updateData(DataRequest dataRequest) ;  how can I use it as I am not using   Observable.just . Let us take my snippet someRepo.updateData(dataRequest)
.observeOn(schedulerProvider.mainThread())
.delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.subscribeWith(dataUpdateObserver()